# Angular PathLocationStrategy refresh url on localhost:4200

Tags: angular, webpack

I have Angular 7.2 and use "useHash": false and add in the src .htaccess file. Start my app on local "npm start" and run in localhost:4200 work. If I navigate to localhost:4200/my-view I see my view but **If reload page (F5 browser reload) I see 404.** Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was proxy.conf.json

```
{
   "/": {
      "target": "http://localhost:8080/api",
      "source": false
   }
}
```

**I change code and works**

```
{
   "/api": {
      "target": "http://localhost:8080/",
      "source": false
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # -- REDIRECTION to https (optional):
    # If you need this, uncomment the next two commands
    # RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    # RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
    # --

    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d

    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

on build/serve

```
 ng serve/build --base-href
```